# convert the type of specific elements in a column from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer

I have a column from a DataFrame which contains mixed element in string Format. I want to convert only the digits which are in string format to integer or generally to numeric values. the word „free“ should be remain.

```
          price type
   0      '100' str
   1      free  str
   2      '80'  str
   3      '200' str
   4      free  str
```

the output should look like as following

```
         price type
   0      100   int
   1      free  str
   2      80    int
   3      200   int
   4      free  str
```

so my questions are:

- there is a way to do that?
- It's possible that a pandas.Series contains elements with different types from       string to integer ?
- there a function which check the type bevor converting this ? something like astype with a conditions

Comment: You can try with list comprehension [`df['price'] = [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in df['price']]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric)

Comment: Or [`df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='ignore')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: thanks @Ch3steR but I still get this error 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnummeric'

the second option with pandas.to_numeric does not change anything.

Comment: It's `isnumeric` you have an extra `m`.

Comment: Opus! That embarrassing! I'm sorry, it works properly thank you again

just for interest it's possible to use apply() with is.numeric() and the condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well directly it is not possible to have a series of 2 different types, but let me try an solution as below.

1. Get all elements of column.
2. Try to convert in your data type
3. Put it in [element]
4. Append to the column.

Use following python code

```
import pandas as pd
""" a.txt
price type
100 str
free str
80 str
200 str
free str
"""
df = pd.read_csv('a.txt', sep=" ")
new = []
for i in df.values:
    try:
        new.append([int(i[0])])
    except:
        new.append([str(i[0])])

df['new'] = new
print(df)
```

Following is how output looks like

```
  price type     new
0   100  str   [100]
1  free  str  [free]
2    80  str    [80]
3   200  str   [200]
4  free  str  [free]
```

Now when you iterate over the values always access 0th position which will be in your required data type

Comment: thank you Danish!